# Acces all off diagonal elements of boolean numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Suppose there is a diagonal matrix M:

```
#import numpy as np

M = np.matrix(np.eye(5, dtype=bool))
```

Does anybody know a simple way to access all off diagonal elements, meaning all elements that are `False`? In `R` I can simply do this by executing

```
M[!M]
```

Unfortunately this is not valid in Python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need the bitwise not operator:

```
M[~M]
```

Comment: Not sure that really extracts off diagonals.
z = np.ones((5, 5), dtype=bool)
z[~z] is an empty array.

Comment: @MarkM That will, however, work when `M` is a diagonal matrix, as specified in the question.

Answer (score 4):

You might try np.extract combined with np.eye. For example:

```
M = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
np.extract(1 -  np.eye(3), M)
# result: array([2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8])
```

In your example it's almost an identity:

```
M = np.matrix(np.eye(5, dtype=bool))
np.extract(1 - np.eye(5), M)
#result: 
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Or equivalently for the OP's case, `np.extract(~M, M)`